# SQLite - > bindingsource, write data back

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, bindingsource

Following code does produce a system invalid operation exception on the dataAdapter_AT.Update(dT) row.

I've been searching all around but cannot figure out how to write data back to the SQLite database once I modify it inside a datagridview.

```
Dim bs_ATDB_database As New BindingSource
Dim dataAdapter_AT As New SQLiteDataAdapter
Dim dttable_AT As New DataTable


Private Sub BT_ATDB_reload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_ATDB_reload.Click

    loadtranslationdatabase()

End Sub

Sub loadtranslationdatabase()
    Dim SQLconnect_AT As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
    Dim SQLcommand_AT As SQLiteCommand

    SQLconnect_AT.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath.ToString) & "\database_AT.db3;"
    SQLconnect_AT.Open()
    SQLcommand_AT = SQLconnect_AT.CreateCommand

    dataAdapter_AT = New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM translations order by stringid asc;", SQLconnect_AT)

    dataAdapter_AT.Fill(dttable_AT)

    bs_ATDB_database.DataSource = dttable_AT

    DGV_ATDB_Database.DataSource = bs_ATDB_database

End Sub


Private Sub DGV_ATDB_Database_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_ATDB_Database.CellEndEdit
    bs_ATDB_database.EndEdit()

    Dim dt As DataTable = CType(bs_ATDB_database.DataSource, DataTable)
    dataAdapter_AT.Update(dt)

End Sub
```

Could someone please explain what I am missing and why it is not updating the database with the edits?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it this way finally:

```
Dim bs_ATDB_database As New BindingSource
Dim dataAdapter_AT As New SQLiteDataAdapter
Dim dttable_AT As New DataTable


Private Sub BT_ATDB_reload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BT_ATDB_reload.Click

loadtranslationdatabase()

End Sub

Sub loadtranslationdatabase()
Dim SQLconnect_AT As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()


SQLconnect_AT.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath.ToString) & "\database_AT.db3;"
SQLconnect_AT.Open()

dataAdapter_AT = New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT rowID, * FROM translations order by stringid asc;", SQLconnect_AT)

dataAdapter_AT.Fill(dttable_AT)

bs_ATDB_database.DataSource = dttable_AT

DGV_ATDB_Database.DataSource = bs_ATDB_database

End Sub


Private Sub DGV_ATDB_Database_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_ATDB_Database.CellEndEdit
bs_ATDB_database.EndEdit()

Dim dt As DataTable = CType(bs_ATDB_database.DataSource, DataTable)
  dataAdapter_AT.UpdateCommand = New SQLiteCommandBuilder(dataAdapter_AT).GetUpdateCommand()
dataAdapter_AT.Update(dt)

End Sub
```

Added the RowID to the selct statement, and added the `dataAdapter_AT.UpdateCommand = New SQLiteCommandBuilder(dataAdapter_AT).GetUpdateCommand()` before the update command.

Comment: I have some questions. What is the SQLcommand_AT for? I didn't think a binding source had an EndEdit event. What is that line for?

Comment: hello @Mary.. the sqlcommand_at is a leftover.. have to remove it.. thanks for pointing it out. As far as I understood the endedit is needed to tell the bindingsource that it can update the content now.

Comment: I meant EndEdit method (not event). When I look at the BindingSource class I don't see it but if it compiles it must be OK. Glad you got it working.

Comment: @Mary , yep, me too.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit(v=vs.110).aspx